# Multiple events are rendering incorrectly in Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using `fullcalendar` to show events from a JSON string.  There are two separate events over the same time period. As seen from the screenshot half way down the rendering swaps sides.

How I can avoid it?

[image: render issue fullcalendar]

Answer (score 0):

Your events should have an ID. Sort the events by ID, and they should display correctly.

Comment: they are sorted by the ID, however the ID is the same for multiple events.  However for the same time period the ID of the events is different.

Answer (score 0):

Ends up to resolve the issue if there are multiple events colliding on the same timeslot, i just add 1 second to the time and it renders them correctly.  No matter what I did with the ID's it didn't work.

Comment: How do events will be triggered..?